# Adding data to Database in Laravel along with validated data and non validated data

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have a form in my view and on submit the fields are validated from the controller and I also need to add some data to database which doesn't need any validation. So how can I store these validated data and non validated(non validated data is set in controller it is not submitted along with the form in the view) data in short code.

This is my Controller

```
public function postRegister($type, Request $request){

    $message = "Succesfully Registered, Login to access your Account";

    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|max:100',
        'legal_type' => 'required|max:25',
        'phonenumber' => 'required|max:12',
        'email' => 'required|max:45',
        'linkedinprofile' => 'required|max:250',
        'address' => 'required:max:350',
        'country' => 'required|max:15',
        'email' => 'required|max:45',
        'password' => 'required|max:120',
        'terms' => 'required'
    ]);

    LegalProfessional::create($validatedData);

//        $lp = new LegalProfessional();
//        $lp->lp_name = $request->input('name');
//        $lp->lp_type = $request->input('legal_type');
//        $lp->lp_phone = $request->input('phonenumber');
//        $lp->lp_email = $request->input('email');
//        $lp->lp_linkedin_profile = $request->input('linkedinprofile');
//        $lp->lp_address = $request->input('address');
//        $lp->country = $request->input('country');
//        $lp->lp_membership_type = 'Premium';
//        //$lp->lp_rfqs = $request->input('name');
//        $lp->lp_username = $request->input('email');
//        $lp->password = $request->input('password');
   // $lp->save();
    Session::flash('message', 'Successfully Registered!');
    return redirect('/login');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `PHP` you can add associative arrays together with the `+` operator. This will basicly add you extra fields to the associative array of `$validatedData`.

```
LegalProfessional::create(
    $validatedData +
    [
        'lp_membership_type' => 'premium',
    ]
);
```

This is in my opinion the easiest and prettiest way to achieve what you want.

**Edit**

Remove terms, use `PHP` built in function `unset()`, that remove items if passed an arrray element.

```
unset($validatedData['terms']);

LegalProfessional::create(
   ...
```

To set a hashed password, just overwrite the `$validatedData` field.

```
$validatedData['password'] = Hash::make($request->input('password'));

LegalProfessional::create(
   ...
```

Comment: I also wants to add hashed password along with that? How it is possible?

Comment: I also wants to remove 'terms' inside $validateData while saving to database, I just wants to use 'terms' in form only.

Comment: To remove a key from an array just do unset($validatedData['terms']) before creation